# HOW to INSTALL Libre Base in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: libreoffice, database

Why no is there no Libre Base included with Libre applications that came with Ubuntu?
HOW do I INSTALL Libre Base in my Ubuntu OS?

Yes I've tried searching this online. So far found nothing that works / is up to date.

(Only similar Question here is over 5yrs old.)
THANKS for reading this!

Comment: You didn't provide us with the Ubuntu version you have installed, but generally `sudo apt install libreoffice-base` should work.

Comment: "nothing that works" is suspicious. Installing a package is very simple. Suggests that you may have some other undisclosed problem that is causing frustration.

Answer (score 4):

Take your pick of the following methods.
Either will work on a properly-functioning Ubuntu system.

**GUI Method**: This will work for most Desktop users.

1. Open the Ubuntu Software application
2. Search for LibreOffice Base
3. Click "Install"

**Shell Method (deb)**: This will work for most Desktop users.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice-base
```

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE!  I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: IT WORKED!  That was SO EASY! (DUH!!) 